# How to insert a pause in between items in AVQueuePlayer?

Tags: swift, avqueueplayer

I am using AVQueuePlayer to playback a batch of audio files. I'd like to insert a pause in between items. Any idea how to do that?

Here the method that adds items into the queue:

```
func addItemToAudioQueue (file:String, last:Bool) {
        let urlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "mp3")
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:urlPath!)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url:fileURL as URL)
        if last {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
        }
        queuePlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by insert `pause`?

Comment: I'd like to add a 5 second or so pause before the next item in the queue starts playing back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `observer` for the `notification` named **`AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`** that will be fired every time an `AVPlayerItem` is finished playing, i.e.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerEndedPlaying), name: Notification.Name("AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: nil)
```

> **AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification**
>
> A notification that's posted
>   when the item has played to its end time.

Next, when the `playerEndedPlaying` method is called after the `notification` is fired, `pause()` the `AVQueuePlayer` initially and then `play()` it again after 5 seconds like so,

```
@objc func playerEndedPlaying(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.player?.pause()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {[weak self] in
        self?.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just found time to try this. It works, thank you so much! One more question though:

I need to have a different pause for different audio items in my queue. How do I pass a variable to this function?

Comment: also, figured out to use `wallDeadline` instead of `deadline` if the counter should work while phone in sleep

Comment: Turns out this does not work with Bluetooth headphones. It's always cutting out a couple of milliseconds when the next item resumes playback.

Any idea how I could solve that?

Comment: ...I'm just going to hack this by inserting audio files with silence in order to create pauses in between items